Where to include jquery script in Blazor web app in ASP.NET Core 8?
I am trying to use the NavBar from the code show here on my Blazor web app in ASP.NET Core 8.
But for the dropdown menu to work, a jQuery script reference must be included in the project.
I have tried to include it in App.razor first on the head section then the body but it didn't work.
I also know that Blazor can not call jQuery directly so at this point I don't know if it is possible to have a NavBar drop down menu in Blazor.
NavMenu.razor (partial code)
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

App.razor:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="AppBase.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />

    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code {
 [CascadingParameter]
 private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

 private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
     ? null
     : InteractiveServer;
}


You do not need to use jQuery to work with dropdown, you could directly use Bootstrap  JavaScript component. here is the sample :
_Host.cshtml:
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorBootstrapApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    @* <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> *@
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorBootstrapApp.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

MainLayout.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>BlazorBootstrapApp</PageTitle>
<NavMenu />

<div class="container">
    @Body
</div>

NavMenu.razor:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">BlazorBootstrapApp</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/counter">Counter</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/fetchdata">Fetch Data</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>



In the NavMenu.razor section you need to add the UL tag with class "navbar" before adding the LI classed "nav-item"
Example
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

